# Grails - How to add log pattern to file appender

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am implementing logging to my application, I am trying to add a pattern to my log file appender,

My code is like this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {

        //  append new appenders of your own and add log level and packages/files like to add.
        rollingFile name: "myAppender",
                    maxFileSize: 1024,
                    file: "C:/GrailsWS/BaseGrails/target/basegrails.log"//""basegrails.log"  //  C:\GrailsWS\BaseGrails\target\basegrails.log

        console name: "myAppender",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }
```

I am following [Grails Logging](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.1.2%20Logging) page, After adding pattern line, my basegrails.log not getting any log data.

Comment: I think that you can't use two appenders with the same name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have appenders of the same name.  I believe what you want to do is give your appenders different names and then apply conversion patterns as needed.  If you want, you can define a variable with a common pattern.  So, something like:

```
log4j = {
    def commonPattern = "%c{2} %m%n"

    appenders {

        //  append new appenders of your own and add log level and packages/files like to add.
        rollingFile name: "rollingLog",
                maxFileSize: 1024,
                file: "C:/GrailsWS/BaseGrails/target/basegrails.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern)

        console name: "stdout",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern )
    }

    // then, use your appenders
    trace stdout ['grails.app', ...]
    debug rollingFile: ['your.package', ...]

}
```